# Where to put function in Rails project that I can call from command line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a function write_to_json() that I want to call only when the data set I'm using changes. For now, I just want to call it manually. Right now I have it in my controller so it runs whenever the page loads. Where should I put this function and how can I access it from the command line? (I want to be able to call it when my app is deployed to Heroku as well.)

Comment: make a service class/module and put your function there, so it can be accessed from rails console, model, controller or any other place in ruby. Then write a rake task that you can execute that calls that function. you can run rake tasks during deploy or add them after_deploy hooks if you are using capistrano.

Comment: Thanks! I have to look into writing rake tasks.